# htaccess SetEnvIf true

Tags: .htaccess

If I want to set an environment variable before RewriteRules are evaluated, [I have to use `SetEnvIf` instead of `SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv). However, `SetEnvIf` requires one to have a condition. As it is, I have:

```
SetEnvIf Request_Method ^ ENV=VALUE
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite's `E` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENV:VALUE]
```

Which will guarantee that it gets set before (or after) rules get applied.

Comment: Just keep in mind that, using this method could change the variable to "REDIRECT_ENV" if a redirect occurs.

Comment: One advantage of this is that it will show up in mod_rewrite's debug log

Answer (score 2):

Using SetEnvIf you can do something like:

```
SetEnvIf ENV  ^(.*)$ ENV=VALUE
```